# What's the meaning of “There can be no more than one package in each folder”？

Tags: ros, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage),it says:"There can be no more than one package in each folder.
This means no nested packages nor multiple packages sharing the same directory."But next to this, a catkin-work space can have many packages,how can it be explained?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259586/what%27s-the-meaning-of-%E2%80%9Cthere-can-be-no-more-than-one-package-in-each-folder%E2%80%9D%EF%BC%9F/) by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the official doc: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

you can have in your workspace several packages(package means here a ROS project with one or more executable applications)

what you are not allowed to do is: putting **package1** and  **package2** in the same folder
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) with karma: 424 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-20**:
sorry to response so late to you.But actually,`package1` and `package2` are in the same folder`workspace_folder/src/`.Sorry to bother you.

**Comment by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) on 2017-04-20**:
see the image and realize that packages inside workspace_folder/src/ are ok ALWAYS, but you CAN NOT put inside package_1 another 2 packages.....

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your catkin_workspace you can have multiple packages. What it says that in one of those packages if you want to have more than one package it is basically called a meta packages. However each metapackage can contain be a package itself. You can't make a metapackage of a metapackage.

So inside your catkin_workspace

- Package 1
- Package 2
  - Meta Package 1 (cant nest further)
  - Meta Package 2
- Package 3

---

Originally posted by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) with karma: 277 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-20**:
Thanks for your answer, I love this Q&A community.Learning ROS is a little hard for me.Hope I can get clear about my questions during learning.

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2017-04-20**:
No problem, the community is for co-existing and learning from each other.